# how to assign NULL value in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Cusid  Cusgroupid  Productid
5      NULL        NULL

ppid   cusgroupid       list    bulk     cost   billing
854    NULL             45.00   42.00    42.00  42.00   
855    2                39.00   36.00    33.00  30.00
```

I want to compare two table, 
expect result is

1, if cusgroupid is 2 only select that row

```
ppid   cusgroupid       list    bulk     cost   billing
855    2                39.00   36.00    33.00  30.00
```

2, if cusgroupid is null only select that row

```
ppid   cusgroupid       list    bulk     cost   billing
854    NULL             45.00   42.00    42.00  42.00
```

Please help!

Comment: 2 condition is 

if cusgroupid is NULL only select that row 

ppid   cusgroupid       list    bulk     cost   billing
854 NULL        45.00   42.00   42.00   42.00

Comment: To be able to help you, we have to understand what you want. I for one don't have a clue, sorry.

Comment: He wants to join the two tables on `cusgroupid` I think

Comment: And this question has already gotten two upvotes, interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not quit sure what you need but does this get you any further?

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE cusgroupid = 2
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE cusgroupid IS NULL
```

or perhaps

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     Table1 t1 
         INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
           ON ISNULL(t2.cusgroupid, -1) = ISNULL(t1.cusgroupid, -1)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE cusgroupid = 2 OR cusgroupid IS NULL
```

Comment: in single query i need ...
plz

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all rows with value 2 or NULL, then use:

```
SELECT ppid, cusgroupid, list, bulk, cost, billing
FROM dbo.YourTable 
WHERE ISNULL(cusgroupid, 2) = 2
```

This will select all rows with `cusgroupid = 2`, and if cusgroupid is NULL, it will also use the value 2 - so those are included as well.